# Deploy tacacs+ on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cisco, rancher, tac

I used TACACS+ using image form [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/lfkeitel/tacacs_plus) that work well with both following methods, until I see the accounting logs:

1. By `docker run`, it can logs the actual switches address for the NAS field.
2. By Rancher Deployment, it logs the Rancher Nodes address instead the switches address for the NAS field, like this [with yellow marked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IC9T.png)

Is it expected behaviour for Rancher/K8s? Or it need some tweak on my deployment? [Here is my Port mapping setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBy0h.png)

Honestly, I'd prefer to use method no. 2 due to its beneficial (scaling, self-healing, and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the culprit by manage `hostNetwork` from false to true, it works now.

```
...
spec:
      containers:
      - image: lfkeitel/tacacs_plus
        name: tacacs
      ...
      hostNetwork: true
      ...
...
```